# union of two select queries with different fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

I have two tables `empmaster` and `allocation`. I used `union` to do sql operation in order to get results from two tables. `empmaster` has `empid` and other `empdetails`. Table `allocation` contains `empid` from `empmaster` as foriegn key another field called `per_alloc`. I need to retrieve `empdetails` which satisfies:

1. `empmaster.empid` not in `allocation.empid`.
2. `empmaster.empid` in `allocation.empid and allocation.per_alloc < 100`.

MySQL query I used is:

```
  select distinct(tbl_empmaster.emp_fname) 
  from tbl_empmaster 
  where tbl_empmaster.emp_id not in(select tbl_allocation.emp_id 
                                    from tbl_allocation)
  union
  select distinct(tbl_empmaster.emp_fname) 
  from tbl_empmaster 
   where tbl_empmaster.emp_id in(select tbl_allocation.emp_id 
                                 from tbl_allocation  
                                 group by emp_id  
                                 having sum(per_alloc) < 100)
```

This only retrieves `empdetails`, say  `tbl_empmaster.emp_fname`, I need to retrieve `sum(per_alloc) from select tbl_allocation`!!! When I tried it gives lot of errors, Can any one show me the correct way, please?

Comment: first sentence is a query and is not formatted, kindly read from - I have two tables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT em.emp_fname, 0 alloc 
FROM tbl_empmaster em
WHERE em.emp_id NOT IN(SELECT emp_id FROM tbl_allocation)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT em.emp_fname, SUM(a.per_alloc) alloc
FROM tbl_empmaster em 
INNER JOIN tbl_allocation a ON em.emp_id = a.emp_id 
GROUP BY a.emp_id 
HAVING SUM(a.per_alloc)<100
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from what I have understood of your problem, I see two problems.

1. There is the unecessary grouping in the subquery of the second select statement. It should be ok to just write
    `select tbl_allocation.emp_id from tbl_allocation where tbl_allocation.per_alloc<100)`*
2. And the answer to your question.change the second select statement to the following, and it should work:
   `select A.emp_fname, B.per_alloc from tbl_empmaster A join tbl_allocation B using(emp_id) where A.emp_id in(select C.emp_id from tbl_allocation C where C.per_alloc<100))`

**Assuming that emp_id is the primary key*